# Notice: Undefined offset:

Tags: php, xml

I finished the code and its like this:

```
<?php
 ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

    function validate_xml(&$filename)
    {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml = file_get_contents($filename); 
    $doc->loadXML($xml); 

    $errors = libxml_get_errors();


    $lines = file($filename);
    $output = fopen('errors.txt', 'a');

    $distinctErrors = array();
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($error->line, $distinctErrors))
        {
            $distinctErrors[$error->line] = $error->message;
            fwrite($output, "Filename: {$filename}.  Error on line: {$error->line}. {$lines[$error->line-1]}\n");

        }
    }

    fclose($output);

}


if(isset($_POST['SubmitCheck'])) {


        $directory = $_POST['Path'];

        if ( ! is_dir($directory)) {
              exit('Invalid diretory path');
                }
                else
                {
                  echo "The dir is: $directory". '<br />';
                        chdir($directory);

                        foreach (glob("*.xml") as $filename) {  
                        validate_xml($filename);                        
                        }  
              }
        }

        else {

        ?>
        <form id="Form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            Path: <input type="text" name="Path"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="SubmitCheck" value="sent">
            <input type="Submit" name="Form1_Submit" value="Path">
        </form>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

And it gives me

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 16032 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16051 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16060 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16075 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16078 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16101 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16110 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined offset: 16167 in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\php-xml\nou.php on line 23
```

The thing is i have 3 big xmls (11MB each).
When i tried the script on 3 small xmls it worked. Also worked separately for each big xml.
I have no idea what do to, i tried increasing the memory limit of php_ini ... still no clue what is happening.

Comment: fwrite($output, "Filename: {$filename}.  Error on line: {$error->line}. {$lines[$error->line-1]}\n");

Answer (score 0):

The code in line 23 has an invalid offset reference (`{$lines[$error->line-1}). 
You wrote:

```
fwrite($output, "Filename: {$filename}.  Error on line: {$error->line}. {$lines[$error->line-1]}\n");
```

I think you want to do:

```
$line_text = $lines[ $error->line - 1 ];
fwrite($output, "Filename: {$filename}.  Error on line: {$error->line}. $line_text \n");
```

The way you were doing, PHP engine was interpreting `$error->line-1` as if `$line-1` was a property of `$error` and not as an arithmetic operation "$line minus 1".

Comment: Well if it is as you say, the script wouldn't work on a single file.
I made one big xml from the 3 xmls (32Mb) and the script works for it, as well as for 3 smaller xmls

Comment: Please, confirm the length of the `$lines` array (by doing eg. `echo count($lines); ` ).

Comment: Filename: 1.xml.  Error on line: 35100. <customer>...</customer>
this is one line of the output errors.txt done for the concatenated xml. The code works great, and $lines has about 40k lines.